# Gathering "Rules" Data from the Api

Tags: google-admin-sdk

From the GSuite Admin Panel you can access the Rules -> Audit page. Does anyone know of a way to pull out that data out using their Api?

I am doing something similar with the Reports section for Tokens, Login, and Admin actions.

Comment: This is also regarding to Google Drive and DLP.

Comment: If this is for the rules in the Admin console, AFAIK, this is not yet available in the Admin SDK. As stated in the [help document](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6321530?hl=en), "From the **Admin console dashboard**, go to **Rules**" and from the [Migrating to the Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/migrate), "the Reporting API for retrieving usage reports for your G Suite domain accounts". You could try and file for a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102), for this functionality. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep thats it. I'll go and fill something out on their feature request page.